# Uniform electric field formation in motional emf induction

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, potential, electromagnetic-induction, dipole

Why is the electric field $E$ across the ends of a conducting rod, when it's moved with a uniform velocity $v$ in a magnetic field $B$, uniform? Wouldn't it vary non-linearly, since there are opposite charges accumulated at each end?

Answer (score 1):

The electric field will actually be constant across the wire. If a certain amount of negative charge move to one side, there will be an equal amount of “positive charge” since the net charge before and after must be zero due to conservation of charge.

Motional emf occurs across a conducting wire when it is placed in a plane perpendicular to a uniform magnetic field, and this wire is moving in a direction perpendicular to the field. Each charge $q$ in the conducting wire experiences a magnetic force given by the Lorentz force

$$F = qv\times B$$

which will reduce to simply $qvB$ since they are perpendicular.

What happens is that negatively charged electrons will accelerate due to this force, negative charge will accumulate on one end of the wire, while a net positive charge will be left behind on the other end of the wire.

The separated charges will  produce an electric field $E$ which exerts an electromotive force on the other charges in the wire.

This electric force will oppose the magnetic force.  Once the electric force is strong enough, it will cancel the magnetic force and the electrons will no longer accelerate, resulting in zero net motion.

We then have the condition $$qvB = qE$$ or $$E=vB$$

will be the electric field in the wire. As we can see from this expression, that given $B$ is a constant and $v$ is a constant, then the electric field is also a constant and does not vary between the ends of the conductor.

Comment: Wonderfully detailed answer, +1. And I knew the bit about  E=vB, making it obvious that E actually is constant, but there's still this; the electric field due to the two positively charged ends is akin to that produced along the axial length of a dipole, right? That varies with distance. So why doesn't that happen here?

Comment: please respond.

Comment: Good question. At any point along the wire, if you were to "slice" it in smaller cylinders, the total amount of negative charge going in will be equal but opposite in sign to that leaving. There is a good paper [here](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Found-Phys-V29-p729-753(1999).pdf) and though it is about a stationary current carrying wire, it is a good resource, and it turns out that a lot of physicist have inaccurate views of this phenomena. Your concern is very valid. Let me know what you think of this paper.